# rcases: How to use tiny font for a text after right brace and make it appear at bottom?

Tags: fonts, cases

How to make `$${\tiny{\mathrm{\forall\ y \in Y_I}}}$$` appear in tiny font and at bottom of right closing brace?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{CTtok_{I_{iv}}} =  \begin{cases}
\quad \mathcal{T}_{I_{iv}}\\
\quad \mathrm{C1_I} = \mathrm{e(g, g)}^{\alpha \mathrm{r_i}}\\
\quad \mathrm{C2_I} = \mathrm{g}^{\beta \mathrm{r_i}}\\
\begin{rcases}
\quad \mathrm{C3_{I_y} = g^{q_y(0)}}\\
\quad \mathrm{C4_{I_y} = H(\mathtt{attr(y)})^{q_y(0)}}\\
\end{rcases} {\tiny{\mathrm{\forall\ y \in Y_I}}}\\
\end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following solution places the term `\forall\ y \in Y_I` in a subscript position to the lower right of the right-hand curly brace.

Note that I've loaded the `mathastext` package, which allowed me to get rid of all `\mathrm` wrappers. I've also employed a couple of `\phantom` statements to align all four `=` symbols.)

[image]

*Addendum*: If you wish to make the term `\forall y\in Y_I` even smaller, you can do so by changing

```
\end{rcases}_{\forall\ y\in Y_I}
```

to

```
\end{rcases}_{\!\scriptscriptstyle\forall y \in Y_I}
```

in the code below. `\scriptscriptstyle` represents a roughly 30% reduction in font size relative to the default style for subscript material, which `\scriptstyle`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathastext} % <-- new
\begin{document}
\[
CTtok_{I_{iv}} =  
\begin{cases}
\mathcal{T}_{I_{iv}}\\
C1_{I_{\phantom{y}}} = e(g, g)^{\alpha r_i}\\
C2_{I_{\phantom{y}}} = g^{\beta r_i}\\
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % to offset the automatic indentation of `rcases` env.
\begin{rcases}
  C3_{I_y} = g^{q_y(0)}\\
  C4_{I_y} = H(\mathtt{attr(y)})^{q_y(0)}
\end{rcases}_{\forall y\in Y_I}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it complicares things, but don't you think greek letters should also be upright?

Comment: @Bernard — My suggestion to use the `mathastext` package was meant purely as a convenience, to avoid having insert all those `\mathrm` wrappers. The OP is entirely free to load a package such as `upgreek` and to write `\upalpha`, `upbeta`, etc. 